# How can I safely alter a texture from multiple threads? (seems like there is no `InterlockedAdd`)

Tags: synchronization, directx, atomic, hlsl, directx-12

According to https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/HLSL_SM_6_6_Int64_and_Float_Atomics.html#interlockedadd, it seems to me that even with shader model 6.6 there is still no `InterlockedAdd` function for floats. I have a ray generation shader which adds to a `RWTexture2D` at a random pixel. How do I ensure that this add is safe when no `InterlockedAdd` is available? What can I do here?